# Django Girl tutorial ( template extending)

Tags: django, django-templates

So I got stuck at the template extending page of the django girls tutorial and I hope someone can see what I've done wrong. (I checked if blog/base.html exists and it does)

`base.html`:

[image]

`post_list.html`:

[image]

Error:

[image]

Comment: Hi Dennis, can you share your stacktrace? And next time copy your codes here as a text, it would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that the file is really encoded as utf8 and contains valid unicode characters.

Some editors, specially in windows tend to do a lot of black magic to display characters correctly.

Try to use VS Code or even Sublime, Atom!

Comment: Thanks man, your a lifesaver. My base.html file was in utf-16 and changed it to utf-8 and it finally works. I really appreciate the help